# What is the maximum cardinality of $C$?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$ be a set with $n$ elements. Let $C$ be a collection of distinct subsets of $A$ such that for any two subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$ in $C$, either $S_1 ⊂ S_2$ or $S_2⊂ S_1$. What is the maximum cardinality of $C$?

1. $n$
2. $n+1$
3. $2^{n-1}+1$
4. $n!$

---

AFAIK : Set $A$ with $n$ elements has total number of subsets is $2^n$ including $\phi$ set. The given condition will be satisfy be all $2^n$ elements, but somewhere answer is given $n+1$ .

> Can you explain in formal way please? what I'm missing here?

Comment: It is not true that if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are _arbitrary_ subsets of $A$ then either $S_1\subset S_2$ or $S_2\subset S_1$. For a counterexample take $A=\{1,2\}$, $S_1=\{1\}$ and $S_2=\{2\}$.

Comment: You are right,that was missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ then we might have $C = \{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$ which would be $3+1$ elements. We absolutely *cannot* have $$C = \{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\},\{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$$because in that case, for instance, $\{1\} \in C$ and $\{2\} \in C$, but we have neither $\{1\}\subseteq \{2\}$ nor $\{2\}\subseteq \{1\}$.

For this reason $C$ has to be a *strict* subset of the powerset of $A$ (unless $A$ has only $0$ or $1$ element), which means it cannot have $2^n$ elements.

As for why it's exactly $n+1$, note that if $A = \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, then $C = \{S_0, S_1, \ldots,S_n\}$ with $S_0 = \varnothing$ and otherwise $S_i = \{x_1, \ldots,x_i\}$ does have the property we want, so the answer is *at least* $n+1$.

There also cannot be more than $n+1$ elements in $C$, because if there were, then there would be $S_i, S_j \in C$ with $S_i \neq S_j$ such that $|S_i| = |S_j|$, by the pidgeonhole principle (there are only $n+1$ different cardinalities available). In that case we cannot have neither $S_i \subseteq S_j$ nor $S_j \subseteq S_i$.

Comment: This holds if $n$ is finite. On the other hand, if $n$ is an infinite cardinal $\aleph_\alpha$ (in which case I grant $n$ would be an unusual letter to use for it), the answer _will_ be $2^n$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm True. For instance on $\Bbb N$, or rather $\Bbb Q$, you can just let $C$ be the set of Dedekind cuts, for instance.

Comment: Hmm, the argument I had in mind for $2^n$ for all infinite $n$ doesn't quite seem to work unless I assume something like GCH.

Comment: @Arthur: Generalizing Dedekind cuts was what I had in mind, but the dense set we get has cardinality $\sup\limits_{\lambda<|A|} 2^\lambda$. This works well as long as $2^\lambda\le|A|$ for all $\lambda<|A|$ -- which is the the case for $|A|=\omega$ and infinitely many larger cardinals (e.g. $|A|=\beth_\alpha$ for any limit ordinal $\alpha$) -- but there may be ones it does not hold for.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You would also need to be careful what order you choose, since the standard ordering of $\Bbb R$, for instance, just gives you $2^{\aleph_0}$ back. You need an ordering where only a few bounded subsets have $\sup$-s, whatever way that is best put into words.

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, one would start by well-ordering $A$, such that a lexicographical order on $2^A$ can be defined.